# Calendar not working in Thunderbird

Tags: 11.04, thunderbird, calendar, google-calendar, lightning

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04, and then installed Thunderbird. I have tried to install two extensions, Lightning and then Provider for Google Calendar. Neither add-on will show up in the add-ons menu after the install and reboot of Thunderbird. I have installed Lightning both manually by downloading the .xpi file from the add-ons site and also trying the built-in utility for downloading add-ons in the Thunderbird menu.

Its strange that the ubuntu repositories does not have thunderbird-lightening installed in it.

Answer (score 3):

The *lightning* extension is now available from the repositories for 11.04 (natty), 11.10 (oneiric) and 12.04 (precise)

By installing `xul-ext-lightning` thunderbird will have a calendar available to add events etc.

```
sudo apt-get install xul-ext-lightning
```

Note - you may be warned about installing the add-on when launching thunderbird up-to-three times.  Each time, tick the box to install the add-on and click the *Restart Thunderbird* button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### The Question

Do you have the Mozilla Team's Ubuntu ppa in your repository? You need to have that to be able to use the newest Thunderbird version and subsequently the Lightning and Google Calendar add-ons.

---

### Adding the repository

To get the latest Thunderbird Client version *(5.0)* first open up your terminal and copy/paste in the following lines.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

If you've already installed Thunderbird but haven't yet grabbed the Mozilla Team's repository until now Thunderbird will just be automatically updated rather than un-installed and then re-installed nor will you lose any of your current settings, extensions, and themes etc.

---

Depending upon the developer and how fast they push release updates for their extensions you might have to go without some of them for a while as the devs catch up to the new version and update the extensions they manage.

Ok after you grab the repository and install the latest Thunderbird you should be able to open up the Add-ons section and install both Lightning and the Provider for Google Calendar without trouble. After you set them up etc restart Thunderbird and it all should still be there... If not, I'd recommend you file a bug report because that would be one in my opinion... Hope this helps you!

Comment: When I installed Tbird5 from those repositories it came with lightning and google calendar already installed.

Comment: @Rob really? That's cool! Thanks for posting that!

Comment: Changing repositories will terribly complicate your security audits because there is no way to properly audit a foreign ppa